How to filter relationships in fastapi sqlalchemy postgresql?
I have three tables: products, last_solds and customers. last_solds table holds the last price of a product sold to a customer. What I want to achieve is to query for all products with the last_sold of a specified customer. How can I do this?
This is what I have tried, but it didn't work, the result is still all products with all last_solds.
Classes:
class Product(Base):
    __tablename__ = "products"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    name = Column(String, nullable=False)
    last_sold = relationship("LastProductSold", back_populates="product")

class Customer(Base):
    __tablename__ = "customers"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    name = Column(String, nullable=False)
    last_sold = relationship("LastProductSold", back_populates="customer")

class LastProductSold(Base):
    __tablename__ = "last_product_solds"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    price = Column(Numeric(precision=15, scale=2), nullable=False, default=0)
    product_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("products.id"), nullable=False)
    customer_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("customers.id"), nullable=False)
    product = relationship("Product", back_populates="last_sold")
    customer = relationship("Customer", back_populates="last_sold")

Schemas:
class LastProductSold(BaseModel):
    id: int
    price: float
    class Config:
        from_attributes = True

class Product(BaseModel):
    id: int
    name: str
    last_sold: Optional[list[LastProductSold]] = Field(default=None)
    class Config:
        from_attributes = True

Endpoint:
@router.get("/products/customer/{customer_id}", response_model=list[Product])
def get_products_for_customer(
    customer_id: int,
    db: Session = Depends(get_db),
):
    products = db.query(Product)
                    .outerjoin(LastSold, LastSold.customer_id == customer_id)
                    .distinct()
    return products 

I have also tried to use joinedload but it still didn't work. If possible I also need to be enlightened on how the orm works, I think my understanding is still a bit off. I tried debugging by printing the result of my queries, but it returns models not objects, and if I don't provide a response model on the endpoint, it'll throw errors when I access the route. Another thing is that if I tried to print the model by parsing it into dict using .dict method, I can't see my outerjoin result.
I tried looking around online and I can't seem to find any relevant explanations regarding my problem, please help me.

You could do it following way
from fastapi import Depends
from sqlalchemy import and_
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session
from typing import List

@router.get("/products/customer/{customer_id}", response_model=List[Product])
def get_products_for_customer(
    customer_id:int,
    db:Session = Depends(get_db),
):
    products_with_last_sold = (
        db.query(
            Product,
           LastProductSold.id.label("last_sold_id"),
            LastProductSold.price.label("last_sold_price"),
        )
        .outerjoin(
            LastProductSold,
            and_(
                LastProductSold.product_id == Product.id,
                LastProductSold.customer_id== customer_id,
            ),
        )
        .all()
    )
    products_list = []
    for product, last_sold_id, last_sold_price in products_with_last_sold:
        product_data = {
            'id': product.id,
            'name': product.name,
            'last_sold': None,
        }
        if last_sold_id is not None:
            product_data['last_sold'] = {
                'id':last_sold_id,
                'price': float(last_sold_price),
            }
        products_list.append(product_data)

    return products_list

So outerjoin now include filter for customer_id,ensuring only last_sold entries for specified customer are joined with each product.
ANd instead of relying on last_sold relationship I manually constructed last_sold data for each product based on join.

Thank you for your answer, I appreciate it a lot. But my question is whether it is efficient? I actually am currently implementing it like that. But from what I understand, I'll get all of the results first and then do a for loop on the results, which makes it inefficient? I am looking for a way to do it directly in one query. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Yes! This is right, You have to set up a joined condition for any join.

May I ask how I can achieve that in this case?
